# Why my functions in the viewModel are invoked on document ready?

Tags: knockout.js

I want the functions to be invoked when buttons are clicked, not on first load of my script.

```
function viewModel() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    self.submit = function () {
        //some code
    };
    self.changeTariffModel = function () {
        //some code
    };

    var instance = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(instance, 
    document.getElementById('ParticipatorHoursSummary'));
}
```

Comment: Please show HTML code too. Otherwise can't understand your problem

Comment: Here is my script code:https://pastebin.com/zx5KhQgt and my html: https://pastebin.com/FJtz0QcV

Comment: So, these two methods get executed on load?

Comment: yes, you have my code on the second comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring binding handlers take care not to evaluate the functions you are attaching to the handler
For example, this:

```
<input type="button" value="Провери" data-bind="click: submit()"/>
```

should be written like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Провери" data-bind="click: submit"/>
```

Notice how i omit the '()' at the end. when you put those parenthesis in you are evaluating the function instead of only assigning the handler